# About periodicity of $f(\frac{m}{n})=\frac{3m-1}{2n+1}$ when $\frac{m}{n}$ is reduced form.

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Consider a function $f\colon\mathbb{Q}_{>0}\longrightarrow\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ such that

$f(x)=\frac{3m-1}{2n+1}$ where $x=\frac{m}{n}$ and $\frac{m}{n}$ is reduced form.
(i.e., $\gcd(n,m)=1$ and $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$)
Questions are,

(1) For which positive rational number $x$, $f(x)<x$?

(2) Let $x_0\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$. Then, construct a sequence $x_1=f(x_0),x_2=f(x_1),\dots,x_k=f(x_{k-1}),\dots$.

For which $x_0$, there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $x_k=x_0$?

(In other words, for which $x_0$ the sequence has periodicity?)

-Progress so far: (1) is easy. For $x=m$ or $\frac{1}{n}$ for some $n,m\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ we have $f(x)<x$.

But for the problem (2), I have no clue. I only know some special cases. If $x_0=2$ or $\frac{1}{3}$ the sequence has period $2$. But I don't know how to derive general solutions.

## How can we find all solutions $x_0$ for the problem 2?

Comment: $1/3 \leftrightarrow 2/7$ and $2/1 \leftrightarrow 5/3$ seem to be the only periodic orbits. There are many pre-periodic orbits leading to these.

Comment: agreed. I tried many calculations, but basically those two cases were only periodic orbits. But do you have any ideas how to prove it?

Comment: If you assume that no reduction is necessary in the first step, it's easy to prove that the only periodic orbits of period $2$ are these.